# Is there a way to Stack a ListView on top of a Container, but is below it?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build an interface in Flutter.

I have a Container with Text (several lines depending on screen size) and a Button. 
I also have a List of Widgets that have to be in front of the Container.

The first item of the list has to be below the Container. The List should be able tp scroll over the Container and the Container should fade away (but not move). The button should still be clickable.

I can't find a way to implement it.

Container

```
Widget container = Container(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(child: Text("BlaBlabla ... long line"),
      Container(child: Text("BlaBlabla ... another long line"),
      Container(child: ButtonWidget(),
    ],
  ),
)
```

List

```
Widget list = ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    CustomWidget(),
    CustomWidget(),
    CustomWidget(),
  ],
)
```

Put together: inside Scaffold Body

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    container,
    Positioned(
    #don't know height of the container
      child: list,
    ),
  ],  
)
```

or

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    container,
    ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        IgnorePointer( #can't click on the real container
          child: Opacity(
            child: container,
            opacity: 0,
            ),
          ),
        list #as column
      ],
    ),
  ],
)
```

or

```
Column(
  children:<Widget>[
    container,
    list, #list can't scroll over the container because the ListView is not the whole body
   ],
)
```

edit: I added some of the combinations I thought could have been the solution, but unfortunately, none of them give worked for my intended purpose.

I appreciate any ideas that help.

It should look similar to the pictures below.

[image: not scrolled]

[image: scrolled]

Comment: Have you tried Stack widget?

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: The Stack Widget was my first idea, but how do I pad the the items of the ListView so it is not in front of the Container? If I put the whole ListView below the Container it can't scroll over the Container.
I also had the Idea to just put the a duplicate Container as the first element into the ListView and wrap it in Opaque, but then I can't click the button of the real Container

Comment: I added more specific information.

Comment: Another aproach would be to be able to let taps pass through the list view, where it is transparent. If anybody knows if there is a possibility for that, that would be great.